# Unable to find item in this array when I do it outside of the map function it works inside it doens't

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calendar with events that are rendered dynamically.

I use this to create the days for the calendar and create an array to display. I try to create an events object containing the details for the events. When I try to outside of the `initialDays` map fuction it works fine and is able to find the object with the correct date and time however when I try to use `find` function inside of the `initialDays` map function I get this error.

```
events.find((item) => {
            return item.datetime == dates
          })
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

```
    createDays()
    {
      this.today = startOfToday()
      this.formatedDate = format(this.today, 'MMM, yyyy')
      this.currentMonth = this.formatedDate

      this.getNewDays = parse(this.currentMonth, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())
      this.firstDayCurrentMonth = parse(this.currentMonth, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())

      let initialDays = eachDayOfInterval({
        start: startOfWeek(this.getNewDays, {weekStartsOn: 1}),
        end: endOfWeek(endOfMonth(this.getNewDays), {weekStartsOn: 1})
      })

      
      
      let events = [{ id: 3, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-10', href: '#' }, { id: 4, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-12', href: '#' }, { id: 3, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-13', href: '#' }]

      events = events.map((events) => {
        return {
          id: events.id,
          name: events.name,
          time: events.time,
          datetime: events.datetime,
          href: events.href
        }
      })

      const findevent = events.find((item) => {
            return item.datetime === '2022-10-10'
          })

          console.log(findevent)


      initialDays = initialDays.map((dates) => {
        return {
          date: format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
          isCurrentMonth: isSameMonth(this.getNewDays, dates),
          isToday: isToday(dates),
          isSelected: isSameDay(dates, this.today),
          events: events.find((item) => {
            return item.datetime == dates
          })
        }
      })


      

      
      this.days = initialDays
    },
```

EDIT ***
`InitialDays` returns a array of dates from start of the current month to end of current month plus 1 week before and 1 week after.

I want the events to be filled in if they match dates. However currently it just fills every date with the all the events. I thought using the find method would work. Date-fns has a ```isSameDay`` function however it only returns true or false. Not sure how to continue...

```
{
    "date": "2022-10-22",
    "isCurrentMonth": true,
    "isToday": false,
    "isSelected": false,
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Date night",
            "time": "6PM",
            "datetime": "2022-10-10",
            "href": "#"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Date night",
            "time": "6PM",
            "datetime": "2022-10-12",
            "href": "#"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Date night",
            "time": "6PM",
            "datetime": "2022-10-13",
            "href": "#"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: where is "length" in your code

Comment: @RahulMohanty it is referred in one of the functions being called in the callback passed to `length`, or so it seems. The fact that the parameter of this callback is named `dates` shows that the asker assumed that inside the callback the whole array will be represented by the parameter, but, in reality its items are represented instead. The same misunderstanding leads to referring to `length`. As about the actual error, at least one item in this array is `undefined` and will throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see the events you are working with:

```
let events = [{ id: 3, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-10', href: '#' }, { id: 4, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-12', href: '#' }, { id: 3, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-13', href: '#' }]
```

The items are objects and

```
      const findevent = events.find((item) => {
            return item.datetime === '2022-10-10'
          })
```

is working for you, which proves that this is operational.

In the snippet below we can see that `map` does not work when you want to call it for an object

```js
      let initialDays = {
        start: new Date(),
        end: new Date()
      };
      initialDays = initialDays.map((dates) => {
        return dates.length
      })
```

therefore `eachDayOfInterval` returns an array (otherwise you would get an error, complaining that `map` is not a function). So, your function of `eachDayOfInterval` does something that you did not share, so it's unclear what this array will contain.

However, it is very safe to assume that the `eachDayOfInterval` returns an array of days (in whatever format). When you do something like

```
initialDays.map((dates) => {
    //...
}
```

you therefore will iterate your dates and each iteration is a date (day). So the naming of `dates` above shows that you misunderstood this part and you assumed that you will have an array of dates inside the `map` callback, but you will have an individual date inside that callback instead, looping through the whole array.

The error suggests that you tried to read the property of `length` on `undefined`. This proves the following:

- your `dates` has at least one `undefined` element, which is the technical reason you get this error
- you treat the individual date as if it was an array of dates

```
items.map(item => something(item))
```

will loop `items` and perform a mapping for each `item`.

Comment: I've added some info into the question in the edit part. Instead of doing find maybe I should create a function that will return the correct event for that date?

Comment: Actually it works just fine... the error was coming from the template part not wanting to render undefined ones generated.

Comment: @DMantas what was working fine: your original approach, or the one I proposed in my answer?